# Registration error

Tags: php, html, registration

This is my registration code, but I don't know what the problem is. The compiler shows the error is "faculty" selection part.

I've checked every single tag, and I think it is correct. I tried to delete the PHP part, and the syntax error went away. I'm guessing that the error is there, but why would the Dreamweaver compiler show the "faculty" part?

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_database('db') or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $myusername = strtolower($_POST['username']);
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $mypassword = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $password1 = strip_tags($_POST['password1']);
    $role = strip_tags($_POST['role']);
    $gender = strip_tags($_POST['gender']);
    $matric = strip_tags($_POST['matric']);
    $college = strip_tags($_POST['college']);
    $faculty = strip_tags($_POST['faculty']);
    $course = strip_tags($_POST['course']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);

    $errors = array();

    if (empty($myusername) || empty($name) || empty($mypassword) || empty($password1) 
            || empty($role) || empty($gender) || empty($matric) || empty($college) 
            || empty($faculty) || empty($course) || empty($email) || empty($phone)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please fill in <b>*ALL*</b> fields! <a href="registration.php">Back</a>';
    } else {
        if ($mypassword != $password1) {
            $errors[] = 'Password does not match';
        }
        if (strlen($myusername) > 30) {
            $errors[] = "Length of username is exceed <b>MAX</b> limit! Must be less than 30 characters";
        }
        if (strlen($mypassword) > 25 || strlen($password) < 6) {
            $errors[] = "Password must be between 6 to 20 characters. <a href='registration.php'>Back</a>";
        }
    }
    if (!empty($errors)) {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br/>';
        }
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO student (username, name, password, role, gender, matric, college, faculty, course, email, phone) VALUES ('" . $myusername . "', '" . $name . "', '" . $mypassword . "','" . $role . "','" . $gender . "','" . $matric . "','" . $college . "','" . $faculty . "','" . $course . "','" . $email . "','" . $phone . "')");
        echo "<strong>You're SUCCESSFULLY  registered! You are now one of the volunteers</strong> You can now <a href= 'index.php'>Login</a> here!.";
        exit();
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="orange">
            <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="orange" align=center style="padding:2;padding-bottom:4">
                        <font size=-1 color="white" face="verdana,arial">
                        <b>Registration Form</b></font></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="white" style="padding:5"><br>

                        <form method="post" action="index.php" name="registration_form" target="_top">
                            <center>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Username </font></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="username" size="60"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Name</font></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="name" size="60"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Password </font></td>
                                        <td><input type="password" name="password" size="60"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Verify Password </font></td>
                                        <td><input type="password" name="password1" size="60"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Role</font></td>
                                        <td><select name="role">
                                                <option value="student">Student</option>
                                            </select></td>
                                    </tr>          
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Gender</font></td>
                                        <td><select name="gender">
                                                <option value="male">Male</option>
                                                <option value="female">Female</option>
                                            </select></td>
                                    </tr>      
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Matric </font></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="matric" size="60"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>College </font></td>
                                        <td><select name="college">
                                                <option value="a">A College</option>
                                                <option value="b">B Residential College</option>
                                                <option value="c">C Campus</option>
                                            </select></td>
                                    </tr>          
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Faculty </font></td>
                                        <td><select name="faculty">            
                                                <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
                                                <option value="XYZ">XYZ</option>
                                            </select></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Course </font></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="course" size="60"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Email </font></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="email" size="60"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Phone Number </font></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="phone" size="60"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1></font></td>
                                        <td><font face="verdana,arial">
                                            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
                                            </font> 
                                            <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan=2><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>&nbsp;</font></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
```

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: What is the error text **exactly**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not closing the else bracket and also `mysql_select_db()` is a function not `mysql_select_database()`.
use this code.

```
 <?php

        $con=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('db',$con) or die (mysql_error()); 

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $myusername=strtolower($_POST['username']);
    $name=strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $mypassword=strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $password1=strip_tags($_POST['password1']);
    $role=strip_tags($_POST['role']);
    $gender=strip_tags($_POST['gender']);
    $matric=strip_tags($_POST['matric']);
    $college=strip_tags($_POST['college']);
    $faculty=strip_tags($_POST['faculty']);
    $course=strip_tags($_POST['course']);
    $email=strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $phone=strip_tags($_POST['phone']);

    $errors = array();

    if (empty($myusername) || empty($name) || empty($mypassword)
    ||empty($password1) || empty($role) || empty($gender) || empty($matric) || empty($college) || empty($faculty) || empty($course) || empty($email) || empty($phone)){
    $errors[]= 'Please fill in <b>*ALL*</b> fields! <a href="registration.php">Back</a>';
    }
    else{
        if ($mypassword!=$password1){
             $errors[] = 'Password does not match';
             }
        if (strlen($myusername)>30){
          $errors[] = "Length of username is exceed <b>MAX</b> limit! Must be less than 30 characters";
         }
        if (strlen($mypassword)>25 || strlen($password)<6){
        $errors[]= "Password must be between 6 to 20 characters. <a href='registration.php'>Back</a>";
        }

        }
        if(!empty($errors)){
        foreach($errors as $error){
            echo $error, '<br/>';
         }
         } 
        else{
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO student (username, name, password, role, gender, matric, college, faculty, course, email, phone) VALUES ('".$myusername."', '".$name. "', '" .$mypassword. "','" .$role. "','".$gender."','". $matric."','".$college."','".$faculty."','".$course."','".$email."','".$phone."')");
        echo "<strong>You're SUCCESSFULLY  registered! You are now one of the volunteers</strong> You can now <a href= 'index.php'>Login</a> here!.";
        exit();
        }
        } 

    else{
    ?>                               
                      <tr><td bgcolor="orange"><table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'><tr>
        <td bgcolor="orange" align=center style="padding:2;padding-bottom:4">
        <font size=-1 color="white" face="verdana,arial">


        <b>Registration Form</b></font></th></tr>
        <tr><td bgcolor="white" style="padding:5"><br>

        <form method="post" action="index.php" name="registration_form" target="_top">

        <center>
          <table>
          <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Username </font></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="username" size="60"></td></tr>
              <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Name</font></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="name" size="60"></td></tr>
              <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Password </font></td>
              <td><input type="password" name="password" size="60"></td></tr>
              <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Verify Password </font></td>
              <td><input type="password" name="password1" size="60"></td></tr>
                <tr>
                <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Role</font></td><td><select name="role">
                <option value="student">Student</option>
                </select></td></tr>          
               <tr>
              <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Gender</font></td>
              <td><select name="gender">
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select></td>
              </tr>      
              <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Matric </font></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="matric" size="60"></td></tr>
              <tr>
              <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>College </font></td>
              <td><select name="college">
                <option value="a">A College</option>
                <option value="b">B Residential College</option>
                    <option value="c">C Campus</option>
                </select></td></tr>          
                <tr>
              <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Faculty </font></td>
              <td><select name="faculty">            
                <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
                <option value="XYZ">XYZ</option>
                    </select></td></tr>

              <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Course </font></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="course" size="60"></td></tr>
              <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Email </font></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="email" size="60"></td></tr>
              <tr><td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>Phone Number </font></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="phone" size="60"></td></tr> 

            <tr>
              <td><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1></font></td>
              <td><font face="verdana,arial">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
                </font> 
                <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan=2><font face="verdana,arial" color="black" size=-1>&nbsp;</font></td>
              </tr>
              </table>
              </center>
              </form>
          <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it in a server... then give a conclusion. dreamweaver is many times wrong while interpretation. it gives many times error while javascript interpretation. you may try any wamp or lamp server.